# how to fix xamarin form listview lag when itemsource are image

Tags: c#, xamarin

how to fix xamarin form listview lag when itemsource are image.
Image are come for folder path i am using FFimageloading for image display

```
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage Aspect="AspectFill"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             BitmapOptimizations="True"
                             DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                             DownsampleUseDipUnits="True"
                             CacheDuration="80"
                             CacheType="Memory"  
                             LoadingPlaceholder="ic_timer"
                             ErrorPlaceholder="ic_spare_active"
                             Source="{Binding DocumentUrl}">

<ffimageloading:CachedImage.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAddDocumentItem}"
                   TargetType="ffimageloading:CachedImage"
                   Value="True">

       <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>

      </DataTrigger>

</ffimageloading:CachedImage.Triggers>

</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Comment: Sorry i update code in proper format

Comment: images how big they are; ?

Comment: Images size around 2 mb and Resolution is 1944 x 2592

Answer (score 0):

If you enable downsampling, please make sure you set correct values for DownsampleWidth or DownsampleHeight. FFImageLoading uses only one of these, preserving correct aspect ratio.

Add and `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` to ListView

Check more samples here

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/tree/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages

Comment: But i am Using Telerik ListView it automate handle RecycleElement